# Work out Analyzer, Version, etc. from Lucene index files?

Tags: java, lucene, version, analyzer

Just double-checking on this: I assume this is not possible and that if you want to keep such info somehow bundled up with the index files in your index directory you have to work out a way to do it yourself.

Obviously you might be using different Analyzers for different directories, and 99% of the time it is pretty important  to use the right one when constructing a QueryParser: if your QP has a different one all sorts of inaccuracies might crop up in the results.

Equally, getting the wrong Version of the index files might, for all I know, not result in a complete failure: again, you might instead get inaccurate results.

I wonder whether the Lucene people have ever considered bundling up this sort of info with the index files?  Equally I wonder if anyone knows whether any of the Lucene derivative apps, like Elasticsearch, maybe do incorporate such a mechanism?

Actually, just looking inside the "_0" files (_0.cfe, _0.cfs and _0.si) of an index, all 3 do actually contain the word "Lucene" seemingly followed by version info.  Hmmm...

PS *other related thoughts which occur:* say you are indexing a text document of some kind (or 1000 documents)... and you want to keep your index up-to-date each time it is opened.  One obvious way to do this would be to compare the last-modified date of individual files with the last time the index was updated: any documents which are now out-of-date would need to have info pertaining to them removed from the index, and then have to be re-indexed.

This need must occur all the time in connection with Lucene indices.  How is it generally tackled in the absence of helpful "meta info" included in with the index files proper?

Answer (score 0):

Anyone interested in this issue:

It does appear from what I said that the `Version` is contained in the index files.  I looked at the `CheckIndex` class and the various info you can get from that, e.g. `CheckIndex.Status.SegmentInfoStatus`, without finding a way to obtain the `Version`.  I'm starting to assume this is deliberate, and that the idea is just to let Lucene handle the updating of the index as required.  Not an entirely satisfactory state of affairs if so...

As for getting other things, such as the `Analyzer` class, it appears you have to implement this sort of "metadata" stuff yourself if you want to... this could be done by just including a text file in with the other files, or alternately it appears you can use the `IndexData` class.  Of course your `Version` could also be stored this way.

For writing such info, see `IndexWriter.setCommitData()`.

For retrieving such info, you have to use one of several (?) subclasses of `IndexReader`, such as `DirectoryReader`.